# Validate Material UI TextField Submit

Tags: reactjs, firebase, material-ui

I'm trying to validate my email and password TextField(s) for a user logging in. I'm able to catch errors via my `handleSubmit` function, but unsure of how to implement those errors into the MaterialUI `error` and `helperText` fields.

Note, I'm using both `material-ui` and `react-bootstrap`, that's why they're mixed.

**Login.js** - where the email and password TextField(s) are

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import firebase from '../firebase';

import { FiLogIn } from 'react-icons/fi';

import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'

import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

export class Login extends Component {
    state = {
        email : "",
        password : ""
    };
    handleChange = (e) => {
        const { id, value } = e.target
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [id] : value
        }))
    };
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { email, password } = this.state;
        firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) => {
            // User is signed in
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Error
        });
    };
    render() {
        const { email, password } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <Form className="sign-in-form">
                    <Form.Row className="align-items-center">
                        <Col xs="auto">
                            <Form.Group controlId="email">
                                <Form.Label srOnly>Email Address</Form.Label>
                                <TextField
                                    id="email"
                                    label="Email"
                                    type="email"
                                    variant="outlined"
                                    aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                                    placeholder="Enter email"
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                        <Col xs="auto">
                            <Form.Group controlId="password">
                                <Form.Label srOnly>Password</Form.Label>
                                <TextField
                                    id="password"
                                    label="Password"
                                    variant="outlined" 
                                    type="password"
                                    placeholder="Enter password"
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </Col>
                    </Form.Row>
                </Form>
                <Button variant="contained" color="primary" className="login" type="submit" onClick={this.handleSubmit}><FiLogIn className="loginIcon" /> Login</Button>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

**handleSubmit Function** - where firebase validation errors are caught

```
    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const { email, password } = this.state;
        firebase
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((user) => {
            // User is signed in
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            // Error
        });
    };
```

Let me know of what I can do here, I'm relatively new with React and always looking to learn new things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this approach:

add an `error` state to your component:

```
state =  {
        email : "",
        password : "",
        error : false,
        errMsg : "" 
    };
```

then change it when error is thrown from the firebase auth action inside `handleSubmit`:

```
.catch((error) => {
            this.state = {error : true, errMsg: error.msg};
        });
```

last, add a conditional TextField to show the error message:

```
{error &&    <TextField
              error
              id="yourErrorId"
              helperText=this.state.errMsg
              variant="outlined"
            />}
```

Comment: This works after changing a few things. Sadly, the conditional TextField displays an additional text field, instead of having separate errors for the email and password fields on the current TextField's

Comment: Try creating a global error message component for your project. That's the best practice. I think MaterialUI already has one better than error TextField, so you should better do a little research. Best regards!

Answer (score 1):

Make an state for error:

```
state = {
    email : "",
    password : "",
    error:"",
};
```

Change it on catching error:

```
    .catch((error) => {
        this.setState({error: error.response.data}) // change it to your error response 
    });
```

And your input should be something like this:

```
<FormControl error={error}>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="email">Email</InputLabel>
    <Input
      id="email"
      value={email}
      onChange={this.handleChange}
      aria-describedby="email"
    />
   <FormHelperText id="email"> {error ? error : "Enter your email address"}</FormHelperText>
</FormControl>
```

Remember to clear error state with handleChange.